# Centralizer of elements in the upper-triangular matrices

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups, centralisers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G=\operatorname{GL}_n ( \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}
)$ such that $n\leq p$. Consider the set $U$ of upper-triangular matrices of $G$
having entries of $1$ on the diagonal. The cardinality of $U$ is $p^{\frac {n(n-1)} 2}$ and $U$ is a subgroup of $G$, in particular $U$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

**Question 1:** Let $M\in U$. Is there a special case for the group $C_{U}(M)$ to be Abelian?

**Question 2:** What is the order of $C_{U}(M)$?

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: I think that in the extreme case ${\rm rank}(M-I) = n-1$, we do have $C_{U}(M)$ Abelian.

Comment: Yes, since then $M$ is a cyclic matrix (one Jordan block) and so its centralizer in the larger group $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is the invertible matrices in the algebra in generates, and so is commutative.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a nice answer here. Certainly it depends on more than just the Jordan type of $M$. For example, in the $3 \times 3$ matrices, the matrix $Z = I + E_{13}$ is in the centre of the Sylow subgroup $U$, so $C_U(Z) = U$ is non-commutative. But $M = I + E_{12}$, which has the same Jordan type, has centralizer $C_U(M) = \langle M, Z \rangle$ which is commutative.

Comment: @MarkWildon: Yes, the second question is complicated, and even the first is more complicated than I first thought ( though I knew the rank(M-I) = n-1 case was clear. More generally, as you say, just knowing the JNF is not enough (though the centralizer (in GL_n) is hard enough  to calculate, given the JNF- that question is considered (and worked out) in the famous Hall-Higman paper of 1956).

Comment: That $n\le p$ allows to treat $G$ as a Lie algebra over $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$, which can ease computations. That is, passing to the $\log$ reduces to the same question in the Lie algebra of upper triangular nilpotent matrices.

Comment: Computer calculations show that if $n \le 7$ and $p=2$ then there are matrices of every Jordan type in $U$ whose centralizer in $U$ is abelian, with the obvious exception of $(1^n)$ and, less obviously, $(2,1,1,1)$ when $n=5$, $(2,1,1,1,1)$, $(3,1,1,1)$, $(4,1,1)$ when $n=6$ and $(2,1^5)$, $(2,2,1^3)$, $(3,1^4)$, $(3,3,1)$, $(4,1,1,1)$, $(4,3)$ when $n=7$.

Comment: I think there is an interesting question here but probably it is hard. As far as I know there is no good description of the conjugacy classes in $U$ for general $n$, even when $n < p$. The number $k(U)$ is the subject of a long-standing 'PORC' conjecture of Higman: see https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/pattern_groups9.pdf

Comment: I can’t find a good answer, but Lemma 4.1 in {}[https://sci-hub.tw/10.1007/s10801-011-0288-2] may be interesting to answer to the second question.

Comment: The lemma in the Azad et al paper is essentially the quantitative version of Geoff Robinson's observation about the centralizers of cyclic matrices.

Comment: I think an answer to this question may exist in the literature but, because of lockdown I can't access all the relevant bits so I'll mention what I've found. First, refer to Lawther's "maximal abelian sets of roots" which addresses a related question in great generality: https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1810/254694/Lawther-2016-Memoirs_of_the_American_Mathematical_Society-AM.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y ...

Comment: Lawther notes in Section 1.1 that in Section 3.3 of Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon (vol 3) they  show that "in an untwisted finite group of Lie type in characteristic $p$, abelian $p$-subgroups correspond to abelian sets of roots" and hence Lawther's memoir yields a solution to this question. Actually for $GL_n$, the associated root system is just $A_{n-1}$ and calculating the maximal abelian sets of roots should be easy enough directly -- but, anyway, Lawther's work covers it. The bit I can't check is what, exactly, GLS3 asserts because I don't have access from home. Perhaps someone else can check.

Comment: The final piece of the jigsaw, once one knows what the maximal abelian subgroups in the upper-triangular matrices are, is to check which of them are centralizers. I'm not quite sure how to do this but am hoping that it can be "read off" from the root group information.