# Upper-triangular matrices as union of centralizers of cyclic elements

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G=GL_n ( \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}
)$ such that $n\leq p$. Consider the set $U$ of upper-triangular matrices of $G$
having entries of $1$ on the diagonal. The cardinality of $U$ is $p^{\frac {n(n-1)} 2}$ and $U$ is a subgroup of $G$, in particular $U$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Recall that an element $M$ in $G$ is said to be a cyclic matrix if the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is equal to its minimum polynomial. Let $C$ be the set of cyclic matrices of $U$.

**Question:** Can $U$ be written as $U=\bigcup_{M\in C}C_{U}(M)$?

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: In other words, does every element of $U$ commute with a matrix in $M\in U$ such that $M-I_n$ has rank $n-1$?

Comment: For $n=3$ the centralizer of $1+E_{12}$ in $U$ consists of matrices $1+aE_{12}+bE_{13}$. No such matrix is cyclic.

Comment: In fact, for $n\leq p$, centralisers of cyclic matrices cover all the elements in $GL(n,p)$. See  Proposition 5.1 in [][https://sci-hub.tw/10.1007/s10801-011-0288-2].

Comment: Can you give the reference to your link? it's blocked where I am.

Comment: Anyway, my argument is correct. It's true that $1+E_{12}$ belongs to the centralizer to a cyclic matrix $M$, but $M$ cannot be chosen in $U$ (which is your requirement).

Comment: See Theorem 1.4 in "Azizollah Azad · Mohammad A. Iranmanesh · Cheryl E. Praeger · Pablo Spiga, Abelian coverings of finite general linear groups and an application to their non-commuting graphs, J Algebr Comb (2011) 34:683–710
DOI 10.1007/s10801-011-0288-2".

Comment: OK thanks, so I confirm the assertion from this paper doesn't rule out my (trivial) counterexample. That proposition doesn't deal with $U$, but with the whole linear group. Computations of centralizers in $U$ for $n=3$ are quite trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort taken to answer the question.

Comment: Anyway Marc Wildon already commented [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362173/centralizer-of-elements-in-the-upper-triangular-matrices) about the centralizer of $I_3+E_{12}$.